# Training with keras+tensorflow in python and predict in C/C++

Tags: c, linux, tensorflow, keras

It is possible to make a fast model with keras with tensor flow as backend and use it to predict in C or C++?

I need to do the prediction inside of a C++ program, but I feel much more comfortable doing the model and the training in keras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you don't need to utilize a GPU in the environment you are deploying to, you could also use my library, called frugally-deep. It is available on GitHub and published under the MIT License: https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep

frugally-deep allows running forward passes on already-trained Keras models directly in C++ without the need to link against TensorFlow or any other backend.

It not only supports prediction with sequential models but also with more complex models build with the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Additionally to supporting many common layer types it can keep up with (and sometimes even beat) the performance of TensorFlow on a single CPU. You can find up-to-date benchmark results for some common model in the [repo](https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep).

By automatic testing frugally-deep guarantees that the output of a model used with it in C++ is exactly the same as if run with Keras in Python.

Comment: In this case I don't need GPU, the target is a rasberypi. If I don't understand wrong your library can evaluate predictions (the forward pass) independently that the net has been trained with keras+tf+GPU. It could be great!!!

Comment: @Mquinteiro Exactly, this is what frugally-deep was made for. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. TensorFlow provides a stable [C API](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c) as well as a C++ one.

For more details, you probably want to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Keras is a python api running over tensorflow that avoid the use of the stable C/C++ API, of course I can translate the model from keras to tf and retrain, but it is not the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cv::dnn module in opencv3.2. See example in the opencv samples.

Comment: yes, and actually I can use a lineal model or even count with fingers, but it is not the question ;)

Comment: Opencv is a c++ library

Comment: yes, but it is not for import keras generated model into c.

Comment: I am no expert but maybe you want to look at this question http://answers.opencv.org/question/172825/keras-tensorflow-opencvdnn/

Comment: Looks like this could be a clue to achieve what I'm looking for, it has two steps, one is to extract the tf model and the second is to use the model with openCV, I need exactly the first step.

Comment: Got it! https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

In simple steps you can do this -

1. Save Keras model into text files in python
2. In C++/C, read those text files, and run the model in a multithreading environment.

**Above Steps in detail**

1. For first step, call save_keras_model_as_text from keras2cpp.py on [Github](https://github.com/upashu1/keras2cpp_multithreading_image_segmentation)-

   '''
   save_keras_model_as_text(model, open('/content/modeltext.txt', 'w') )
   save_keras_model_as_text(model, open('/content/modellayersonlytext.txt', 'w') , noweight=True)
   '''
2. In c++/c projects, include [keras.h /keras.cpp](https://github.com/upashu1/keras2cpp_multithreading_image_segmentation) files.
3. convert input image into Keras format or read input image into Keras format from a file.

'''

```
//assume dst is pointer to an image object. This 
//can be of CxImage / CImg /OpenCV or of any other 
//library.

int h = dst->GetHeight();
int w= dst->GetWidth();;
    
int *img = new int[h*w*3];
int *img_r = img, *img_g =&img[h*w], *img_b=&img[2*h*w];
   
    
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w;x++) {
             RGBQUAD rgb= dst->GetPixelColor(x,y);
             *img_r= rgb.rgbRed; img_r++;
             *img_g= rgb.rgbGreen; img_g++; 
             *img_b = rgb.rgbBlue; img_b++;
            
          }
         
       }
```

'''

4. Call [ExecuteKerasSegmentation](https://github.com/upashu1/keras2cpp_multithreading_image_segmentation).

   '''

   ```
    //text files in which keras model is saved.
    char *modelfile ="modellayersonlytext.txt";  
    char *weightfile="modeltext.txt";

    int *result = ExecuteKerasSegmentation(img, h, w, 3, modelfile, weightfile);
   ```

   '''
5. result contains the segmentation result. You may save it into pgm file or convert it into your image library object and use it further.

'''

```
save_image_pgm("segmentation_map.pgm",result,h,w,127); //127 is scaling factor for binary images.
```

'''